# Determing what button submitted a form via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that can be submitted by two buttons. I want one button to simply save the content of the form and another to save the content and then clear it. I am using ajax to submit the form. I currently have the two buttons named the same name and they each contain a different value. Here are my html buttons,

```
 //Saves the form
 <button type="submit" name="action" value="save_form" 
         class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
 //Saves the form and clears it
 <button type="submit" name="action"  value="new_form"
         class="btn btn-warning">New Form</button>
```

I am using ajax to submit the form and this is the code I use to get the value of the action button that submitted the form,

```
'action' : $('button[name=action]').val()
```

The entire thing works but the problem is that when I submit the form using the `new_form` button the above jQuery code still sets the value of the submit button as `save_card` instead of `new card`.

I have switched the order of how the buttons appear on the form and the above jQuery code takes the value of whatever button appear first that is named `action`.

Why is it doing this? How can I detect what button submitted the form?

**jQuery that submits the form via Ajax**

```
$(document).on('submit', '#edit_form', function(event) {
    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();

    // get the form data
    var formData = {
        'did'    : $('input[name=did]').val(),
        'front'  : $('textarea[name=front]').val(),
        'back'   : $('textarea[name=back]').val(),
        'cid'    : $('input[name=cid]').val(),
        'action' : $('button[name=action]').val()
     };
     // process the form
     $.ajax({
         type        : 'POST',
         url         : '../API/api.php',
         data        : formData, 
         success: function(data) {
                      //do something
                  }
     });

 });
```

Comment: post your javascript also.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis Posted the javascript

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling `'action' : $('button[name=action]').val()` inside the click event of the button then use

```
'action' : $(this).val().
```

`$(this)` will refer to the element that was clicked. and `$('button[name=action]')` would return all the button having name = action and you are having two button named action so whatever first encountered is returned.

**Update**

Try something like below:

```
$('button[name=action]').click(function(event) {
    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page

    // get the form data
    var formData = {
        'did'    : $('input[name=did]').val(),
        'front'  : $('textarea[name=front]').val(),
        'back'   : $('textarea[name=back]').val(),
        'cid'    : $('input[name=cid]').val(),
        'action' : $(this).val()
     };
     // process the form
     $.ajax({
         type        : 'POST',
         url         : '../API/api.php',
         data        : formData, 
         success: function(data) {
                      //do something
                  }
     });

 });
```

Comment: I added the complete code for how my form is submitted. I am not sure if this method will work for how my code is written. Please let me know if it will work.

Comment: The beginning of my code needs to be this `$(document).on('submit', '#edit_form', function(event)` using the `$(document).on` because the form I am submitting is created dynamically and without `$(document).on` the form that was created dynamically will be removed.